# How to create custom feeds processor?

Tags: 7, commerce, feeds

I need to create a custom feeds processor. Basically my client will upload a csv file they have received from amazon or some other source and it will create an order for them. It will allow them to manage all their orders in one place. I know I need to create a custom feeds processor but am unsure on how to do that?

Comment: I have used [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module with excellent results, You can use some hooks to create your own processor, you can get a reference copying one of the contributed modules to check how to do it.

Comment: I have used something similar, but to create nodes from an XML file, surely this can be modified to use CSV. Check out [this tutorial](http://drupalwalla.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/use-feeds-module-to-import-xml-data-in.html).

Comment: "use some hooks" ? Sorry, this is a terrible answer. Try to add more relevant info next time, maybe even an example of your own.